# How do I get Newtonsoft.Json.Schema to resolve a subschema?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to get Newtonsoft.Json.Schema to parse the schema at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceListing.json# but it's failing to parse the subschema referenced as resourceObject.json#. It correctly figures out the url should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceObject.json# but fails to load it with this error:

> Could not resolve schema reference 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceObject.json#'. Path 'properties.apis.items', line 10, position 22.

I validated both schemas using http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ which seems to use the same library I'm using. I also used that site with my referenced schema (resourceListing.json) to validate what I'm trying to validate and it worked.

I tried to load it myself using the JSchemaPreloadedResolver as suggested in [this documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/LoadingSchemas.htm) but that results in the exact same error. Here's the code I used with RestSharp as my client library.

```
var dependencyResolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver();
dependencyResolver.Add(
   new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceObject.json#"),
   client.Get<string>("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceObject.json#")
);
var schema = JSchema.Parse(client.Get<string>("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v1.2/resourceListing.json#"), dependencyResolver);
```

Comment: Does restsharp successfully download it?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I am now reproducing the same issue using the schema locally after modifying the id and #ref accordingly. It doesn't look like JSchema.Parse uses the JSchemaResolver at all.

Comment: have you tried using JavaScriptSerializer class of .net?

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar does it support JSON Schema? I'm not finding that support if it's there.

Comment: yes make a model class of it and it will serialize and de serialize for you

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar I don't need to deserialize the json, only validate it against the public schema. I already have classes for serializing data and want to ensure that they match the schema.